# On submit on a jsp page run a java function and the return to the same page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

The title might be a bit confusing but let me explain.

I have a table at the top of the page that is filled from a MySQL database loop. The table is a simple timesheet. It has a date, hours work and description columns. I can fill this fine. Just below this is a form to add to this table. It will send the information to a servlet to update the database. Still no problem but at the end of the servlet, I need it to go right back to the initial page so it will show the now updated table.

What function can I use for this?

Would it be a redirect to the original page URL?

Comment: You can simply return `JSP` from which you are rendering your table with updated object in `Model`

Comment: If you want skip page reloading use ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){}
```

you could use

```
response.sendRedirect("your link");
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add method like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String saveNewData(ModelMap model, Dto dto){
  // Request Type and dto will be according to your use case .
  model.put("obj",yourservice.save(dto));
  return "yourjsp" ;
}
```

And in jsp paint table with obj